# How do i restart the process from my last output and create a file which can store the data of last output?

Tags: c#, .net, file

How do i create a file which can store the output info? for example, i need to get a output where the name repeats 10000 times.. once i stop running the program and start again, it should display the new outputs with the values of the old one.. And if i stop it in between, say 4000th time, it shud start again from 4001 and not all over again.. and how do i use file in this program? could someone help me with the entire program? 
The program is -

```
namespace Time_Writer
{
    class Program
    {
        static int count = 1;
        static double seconds;
        private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Elapsed +=new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(aTimer_Elapsed);
            aTimer.Interval = 5000;
            aTimer.Enabled = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Exit The Program\n");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
        private static void aTimer_Elapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name is Yap {0}", e.SignalTime);
            seconds += 5;
            count += 1;
            if (count>10)
            {
                aTimer.Enabled = false;
                Console.WriteLine("\n\nTimer is off at {0}\n\n", e.SignalTime.TimeOfDay.ToString());
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what are you having problems with? What have you tried? Is this homework?

Comment: @Jason i'm learning. i want to know how to create a file and store the values of the previous output it. And the next time i run the same program, the name shud start repeating from where it stopped last time.

Comment: Once you write the file with values, just read it back to resume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this example I just save the bits of the count variable to a file in the same directory.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReadCountFromFile();

        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        aTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(aTimer_Elapsed);
        aTimer.Interval = 5000;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter To Exit The Program\n");
        Console.ReadLine();

        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new EventHandler(CurrentDomain_DomainUnload);
    }

    private static void ReadCountFromFile()
    {
        try
        {
            if (File.Exists(".\\mynumber.dat"))
            {
                using (var file = File.Open(".\\mynumber.dat", FileMode.Open))
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
                    file.Read(bytes, 0, 4);
                    count = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
                    Console.WriteLine("Count = {0}", count);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Problem reading file.");
        }
    }

    static void CurrentDomain_ProcessExit(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var file = File.Open(".\\mynumber.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            var buffer = BitConverter.GetBytes(count);
            file.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @375487 If i have to reset the count, how do i do it? do i have to create a new file? And i would also like to how to reset the count after each day automatically.

Comment: 1. if you have to reset the count, you just reset the count i.e. you set count=0 :)
2. if you want to reset it on timer, use System.Threading.Timer.

Comment: And how would i do that? could u just give me the code?